# Edittext can not be converted to string

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

I created a message using EditText for the criticism and suggestion that will be sent using intent email, but when I picked up the message there was no result.

I took a string of using Edittext

```
message = msg_feedback.getText().toString();
```

and if I use directly

```
message = msg_feedback.toString();
```

then it appears in the following log

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{2bd670a VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0f00ce app:id/msgFeedback}

following his complete code

***Activity***

```
@InjectView(R.id.msgFeedback)
EditText msg_feedback;

String message;

message = msg_feedback.getText().toString();
```

***Layout***

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/msgFeedback"
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:maxLines="9"
    android:lines="9"
    android:maxLength="397"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:breakStrategy="balanced"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nohpFeedback" />
```

Comment: And what do you need? What's your question?

Comment: So the getText() call returns nothing? You get the object's name if you toString() the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the message from editext as string using this approach.

```
message = msg_feedback.getText().toString();
```

Now you can use message as string which will be the text from the edittext.

and here `message = msg_feedback.toString();`
 You actually getting the name of your EditText as string.

Comment: post where you are using this string.

Comment: yes actually the problem there, but now it is solved

Answer (score 0):

> and if I use directly
>
> message = msg_feedback.toString();

Why you are using it? This is not a direct way, But this is incorrect way. This will not give you the text which `EditText` contains, it will call `toString()` of object of `EditText`.

So below  way is correct way, which you are using already

```
message = msg_feedback.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`EditText`  is a class and `msg_feedback` is instance or object of `EditText`

`getText()` is a method of `EditText` that return `CharSequence`

`toString()` is a method of `String` class and `toString()` use to  convert objcet to `String`

If you directly convert `EditText` object to String object  it is return the Object reference and information about `EditText`

Carefully see it. It is your output..

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{//Class Info
    2bd670a VFED..CL. ......I. 0,
    0-0,
    0 
    #7f0f00ce 
    app:id/msgFeedback //EditText ID
}
```

not the text inside `EditText` . 
So If you want text inside the `EditText` you must use

```
msg_feedback.getText().toString();
```

Do you understand? If any query feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

this code is correct

```
message = msg_feedback.getText().toString();
```

sorry, everything turns out my carelessness, this is not about the actual conversion.
but the string access problem, I call in the function keys I forgot to change its access.